# Получение полного адреса загружаемой фотографии?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Подскажите, есть ли возможность получения полного адреса того файла (картинки) который пользователь вставляет в input type="file" (где данный фаил находиться сейчас у пользователя на компьютере)?

```js
window.onload = function() {

  function uploadPhoto() {

    var file_api = (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) ? true : false;

    $(".table_casino__uploadImg_upload").change(function() {
      var file_name;
      if (file_api && ($(this).prop('files')[0])) {
        file_name = ($(this)).prop('files')[0].name;
        console.log(file_name, $(this).prop('files')[0]);
      } else {
        file_name = $(this).val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\", '');
      }

      if (!file_name.length)
        return;

      if ($(this).prev(".file_upload__text").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).prev(".file_upload__text").text(file_name);
      }

      $('.table_casino__uploadImg_text').text(file_name);

    }).change();


    $(window).resize(function() {
      $(".table_casino__uploadImg_upload").triggerHandler("change");
    });

  }
  uploadPhoto();

}
```

```css
.table_casino__uploadImg_lable {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 264px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table_casino__uploadImg_image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 264px
}

.table_casino__uploadImg_text {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: none;
}

.table_casino__uploadImg_upload {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(2);
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="table_casino__uploadImg_lable">
<img class="table_casino__uploadImg_image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x450" alt="name">

<p class="table_casino__uploadImg_text">Файл не выбран</p>
<input class="table_casino__uploadImg_upload" type="file" name="fileImg[]" accept="image/jpeg,image/png"></label>
```

Мне удалось найти что File API дает возможность определить имя вставляемого изображения.(Отображаю в консоле) Я же хочу получать весь путь, и после того как пользователь "вставил" фото, обновлять (визуально) src путь .table_casino__uploadImg_image тем адресом который есть у пользователя на компьютере, тем самым показывая пользователю его картинку (но при этом не отправляя, пока что данные на сервер)

Comment: Нет, такой возможности нету. Узнавать пути пользователя - дыра в безопасности.

Answer (score 0):

Все сохраняется в blob. Вы можете получать URL-адрес blob от браузере где находится ваш файл.

Эти URL-адреса могут использоваться только локально в одном экземпляре браузера и в том же сеансе.

Comment: Можно подробнее? Или как-то мой пример доделать что б можно было увидеть то изображение что я(или Вы) пытаемся загрузить... ?